# git ignore multiple matching files

Tags: git

I try to ignore file in a directory by relative path. E.g. I have several directories in working tree `lib/file.f` and I want all occurrences of this file to be ignored. I tried

```
lib/file.f
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Place

```
*/lib/file.f
```

in your `.gitignore`. This will cause git to ignore any file of the form `project/<DIR>/lib/file.f`, assuming `.gitignore` is in the `project` directory.
To make git ignore `lib/file.f` two directories down, you'd also have to add

```
*/*/lib/file.f
```

to the `.gitignore`, and so on.

Vastly simpler of course, would be to place

```
*file.f
```

in `.gitignore` to block all files named `file.f`, but your question seems to suggest there is at least one file by that name you wish not to ignore.

Comment: @Holf The `file.f` doesn't work, because you reference file itself, without path (and you probably don't have `file.f` in your project's root folder). That's why _unutbu_'s answer have all examples with full path. The `*file.f` works, because you used `*` wildcard and thus it will ignore _any file_, that matches your pattern -- is it really, what you wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

also you might want to remove the file from git cache, in order to check what you just ignored:

```
git rm --cached lib/file.f
```

this is if you already added the file to git index

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify all sub-folders under specific folder use `/**/`. To ignore all `file.f` files in a `/src/main/` folder and sub-folders use:

```
/src/main/**/file.f
```